# AddSeries parameters

Tags: json, dojo, charts, dojox.charting

I try hard to get some functional charts with dojo...

I want to create a stacked area chart with 3 lines. For the "bas", "moy" and "haut" as you see in the JSON data.

```
    var jStore = {"identifier":"mois",
                "items":[{"mois":1,  "bas":98,   "moy":122.5,   "haut":147},
                         {"mois":2,  "bas":91,   "moy":113.75,  "haut":136.5},
                         {"mois":3,  "bas":91,   "moy":113.75,  "haut":136.5},
                         {"mois":4,  "bas":84,   "moy":105,     "haut":126},
                         {"mois":5,  "bas":77,   "moy":96.25,   "haut":115.5},
                         {"mois":6,  "bas":63,   "moy":78.75,   "haut":94.5},
                         {"mois":7,  "bas":49,   "moy":61.25,   "haut":73.5},
                         {"mois":8,  "bas":42,   "moy":52.5,    "haut":63},
                         {"mois":9,  "bas":49,   "moy":61.25,   "haut":73.5},
                         {"mois":10, "bas":70,   "moy":87.5,    "haut":105},
                         {"mois":11, "bas":77,   "moy":96.25,   "haut":115.5},
                         {"mois":12, "bas":84,   "moy":105,     "haut":126}]
             };
```

I want to put int the x axis the months as it seen in the code. Call the specific data in the JSON to create every line.

```
dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
                var chart1 = new dojox.charting.Chart2D('chart1');
                chart1.addPlot('default', {
                        type: 'StackedAreas',
                        markers: true,
                        tension: 'S',
                        lines: true,
                        areas: true,
                        labelOffset: -30,
                        shadows: {
                            dx:2, dy:2, dw:2
                        }
                     });
                chart1.addAxis('x', {max:12, 
                   labels:[
                      {value: 0, text: ""},
                      {value: 1, text: "Jan"},
                      {value: 2, text: "Feb"},
                      {value: 3, text: "Mar"},
                      {value: 4, text: "Apr"},
                      {value: 5, text: "May"},
                      {value: 6, text: "Jun"},
                      {value: 7, text: "Jul"},
                      {value: 8, text: "Aug"},
                      {value: 9, text: "Sept"},
                      {value: 10, text: "Oct"},
                      {value: 11, text: "Nov"},
                      {value: 12, text: "Dec"}
               ]});
                chart1.addAxis('y', { vertical: true, max:200, includeZero: true });
                chart1.addSeries('Basse', (jStore, {query: {bas: "*"}}, "bas"),{ stroke: 'red', fill: 'pink' });
                chart1.addSeries('Moyenne',(jStore, {query: {moy: "*"}}, "moy"), { stroke: 'green', fill: 'lightgreen' });
                chart1.addSeries('Haute',(jStore, {query: {haut: "*"}}, "haut"), { stroke: 'blue', fill: 'lightblue' });
                chart1.render();
                var anim1a = new dojox.charting.action2d.Magnify(chart1, "default");
                var anim1b = new dojox.charting.action2d.Tooltip(chart1, "default");
                var legend1 = new dojox.charting.widget.Legend({
                    chart:chart1
                },"legend1");
                chart1.render();
            });
```

It doesn't work, I don't know wath I have to put instead of `(jStore, {query: {haut: "*"}}, "haut")` to call my specific data.

please help ! thanx a lot.

Comment: I've resolved my problem. I've create an AJAX function to setup my datas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the official docs [Using dojo.data Data Sources with Charts](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojox/charting#using-dojo-data-data-sources-with-charts):

> dojox.charting.DataSeries is used to connect to dojo.data stores. User should create it and pass it instead of a data array in chart.addSeries() call.

Example of use can be found in `dojox/charting/tests/test_DataSeries.html`.

Another missing piece in your example is a store object. Somehow you try to pass a JSON structure around, which has data, but no required methods. You should create a data store first from your data. I have no idea what data store you want to use, but if all you want is to show your data structure, you can use `dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore`:

```
dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore");

var jStore = ...; // not really a store, but your JSON-like object
var realStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({data: jStore});
...
chart1.addSeries(
  'Basse',
  new dojox.charting.DataSeries(realStore, {query: {bas: "*"}}, "bas"),
  {stroke: 'red', fill: 'pink'}
);
```

Use link above to learn about `dojox.charting.DataSeries`. Read all about `dojo.data` in the official documentation: http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojo/data